# Fill an array with numbers given by the user adding a number each time he presses the button

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a basic form with a button and a textbox to insert a number

I want to keep the number inserted in the first index of the array, then if I put another number and I click the button, I want that number to be stored in the second index of the array and so on

I have to make a loop to increment the index but if I use the loop, the first number I put in the box, it's going to be stored in all the indexes of the array

Here's my code (doesn't work)

```
public partial class EXERCISES_ARRAYS : Form
{
    int[] numbers = new int[5];

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;

        int insertedNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtInsertedValue.Text);

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            numbers[i] = insertedNumber;
            i++;

            if (i == 5)
            {
                btnAdd.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you put the variable i in the class scope, besides your number array and just keep the code within your wrong loop in the click method, it will work

Comment: Edit: it's still doing the same. I put a number in the textbox, then press the button and all the positions in the array store that number. I want to write a number in a textbox and press the button. When pressing the button, the number is stored in numbers[0]. If I then put another number and click the button, that number gets stored in numbers[1] and so on

Comment: you are much,much better off with a list as per sania answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You want a List, rather than an array. That will take care of all of this for you:

```
public partial class EXERCISES_ARRAYS : Form
{
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        numbers.Add(int.Parse(txtInsertedValue.Text));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to add a for loop for this. Try this

```
int[] numbers = new int[5];
int i = 0;

private void BtnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      int insertedNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtInsertedValue.Text);
      numbers[i] = insertedNumber;
      i++;
      if (i == 5)
            {
                btnAdd.Enabled = false;
            }
}
```